# Add a date and reload page with new date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker control which i used for date selection in my Razor view
Definition is like this

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "datepicker form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
 </div>
```

And in javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Date").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        altFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',
        dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "2014:2050"
    });
});
```

And i have a button control which should add a day to the selected date and redirects the page to another url with the new date param

```
 function loadForPreDay() {
    alert("s");
    var d = $("#Date").val();
    alert(d);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
    var nd = new Date(newdate);
    alert(nd);
    window.location.href = '/Attendance/Select?date=' + nd;
}
```

Which is calling from

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                   @Html.ActionLink("Previous day", null, null, null,new {@class="btn", onclick="loadForPreDay()"});
 </div>
```

But for me its not working.
Also the Date field contains time information also ( BY default todays date value is choosen )
How can i make it to work with previous day button

Comment: There is a `defaultDate` options as part of the date picker options which you can use. After you pass the time selected you need to collect it from the query parameters and use that to set the `defaultDate`

Comment: How can i handle the Previous day button click ? ie reduce date by 1 day and the reload page with new url

Answer (score 0):

Modify Javascript code  to

// to get query string parameter

```
 function GetParameterValues(param) {
      var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
      for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
        if (urlparam[0] == param) {
          return urlparam[1];
        }
      }
    }


$(document).ready(function () {
var myDate = GetParameterValues('date');
if(myDate != null && myDate != '')
{
    $("#Date").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        altFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',
        dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',
        defaultDate:myDate,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "2014:2050"
    });
}
else
{
   $("#Date").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        altFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',
        dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "2014:2050"
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Ok . But still how about second question ? On Previous button click event reduce the selected date to a day back and call the url with new date?

Comment: Modify function loadForPreDay as below

function loadForPreDay() {
 var date = new Date($("#Date").val()),
 date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  window.location.href = '/Attendance/Select?date=' + date;
}